# How to install a mainline kernel during install?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, kernel, i915

Due to a bug in kernels 4.3-4.8 I am not able to install Ubuntu on my PC. 
Here's the [bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1609242): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1609242

I would like to do a clean install but I don't want to revert back to 14.04.

Is it possible to install a mainline kernel (the last version to work with my PC is 4.2.8) during the install process?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is not supposed to run with kernel 4.2. You need to use 14.04, if there is no other choice.

Comment: This bug will be fixed soon. Then you will be able to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: Dude. I already upgraded to 16.04. Since the Kernel it ships with is broken I installed 4.2.8 and it works fine. How do you know it will be fixed soon?